# TrickleEdit test question

Tags: discussion

This is a test question used while developing [an extension](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12663/trickleedit-queuing-edits-to-prevent-flooding).

Please do not upvote or downvote this question.

This question will be deleted when testing is complete.

Comment: But I LOVE this question!  Can't I upvote it?

Comment: Cause @Bob asked. This is fine. And not in the drinking coffee in a fire sense. At most, drinking good coffee in a nice cool room sense.

Comment: I did not know questions could tickle...OH wait....icky!

Comment: reminded https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/92dd8/test_post_please_ignore/