# TrickleEdit test question 2

Tags: discussion, editing

As asked by @Bob in [TrickleEdit test question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12666/trickleedit-test-question):

> This is a test question used while developing an extension.
>
> Please do not upvote or downvote this question.
>
> This question will be deleted when testing is complete.

My question: Is that question on-topic for Meta SU?

This is a rhetorical question to allow posting an actual question.  Please do not post answers.  Also, don't close it as a dupe either please.  Testing edit 2

Comment: I added proper attribution to avoid plagiarism, and included an actual question in the question to avoid closure as unclear what you were asking.  No need to thank me; glad to help with this effort.  I didn't want the question to get closed prematurely for newbie mistakes.  It had already attracted a downvote.  :-)

Comment: How does a fake test question get close votes?  It is a bloody test question.  Please think about this for a minute people, if you vote to close this question, you will be listed as somebody who voted to close a test question.  The users who participate in the test will simply reopen it.  *At the very least you are going to get pinged by several people asking you to explain your close vote.*

Comment: @Ramhound, you missed the smiley face at the end.  Sometimes my humor is just too dry.  Figured nobody would take something that obviously ridiculous seriously.

Comment: Well this question really did receive a downvote....My ability to process sarcasm is extremely limited, I am a serious guy, I am even serious when I visit Disney World...